# Print information in Modal (of Bootstrap)

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

In my search input give me result about keywords like below:

![While of result's] https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VaWl.png

and my target is get more information by open Modal if click any result:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/qU36A.png

I want to select more information from mysql on open model. How can I do this?

Below is my code:

```
<body>
      <h1>חפש פריט</h1>
      <br>
      <form action="search.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="keywords" class="form-control" style="width: 250px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;display:inline;" placeholder="הקלד שם של פריט..." /><button type="submit" name="search" class="btn btn-primary">חפש</button>
      </form>
      <br>
      <?php
      $keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
      $ok = 1;
      if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
      if(empty($keywords)) {
      echo '<div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        <strong>שגיאה:</strong> הקלד מילות חיפוש
      </div>';
      $ok = 0;
      }
      if(!empty($keywords) && !preg_match("/[A-Za-z0-9א-ת\.\,\_\- ]/", $keywords)) {
      echo '<div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        <strong>שגיאה:</strong> הזנת תווים לא חוקיים
      </div>';
      $ok = 0;
      }
      else if($ok !== 0) {
      $search_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `list` WHERE `Name` LIKE '%$keywords%';");
      if(mysql_num_rows($search_sql) < 1) {
      $status = "
      <div class='alert alert-warning'>
      <strong>לא מצאנו</strong> תוצאות עבור חיפוש זה ($keywords)
    </div>
    ";
      }
      echo '<div class="container">
      <h2>תוצאות חיפוש</h2>
      <br />
      '.$status.'';
      while($result = mysql_fetch_array($search_sql)) {
      printf('
      <div class="well" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">%s</div><br />
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
      ', $result['Name']);
      }
      echo '</div>';
      }
      }
      ?>
```

EDIT: Now I am can select the information form the mysql but only with while of "$i"..

```
with this:
 echo '<div class="container">
  <h2>תוצאות חיפוש</h2>
  <br />
  '.$status.'';
  $i = 1;
  while($result = mysql_fetch_array($search_sql) and $i < 1000) {
  printf('
  <div class="well" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal'.$i.'">%s</div><br />
    <div id="myModal'.$i.'" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">'.$result['Name'].'</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>'.$result["Description"].'</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">סגור</button> <span style="float:left;">'.$result["Date"].'</span>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
  ', $result['Name']);
  }
```

But, it is not working good. If I'm click on any-result the modal is open with same result:
i.stack.imgur.com/SKrka.png

So, I want anything more proffesional for this..

Answer (score 0):

Does not matter,
I am just replace the i var to result-id from the mysql
Replace this:

```
  <div class="well" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#openM'.$i.'">%s</div><br />
<div id="openM'.$i.'" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
```

To:

```
  <div class="well" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#openM'.$result['ID'].'">%s</div><br />
<div id="openM'.$result['ID'].'" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
```

Have a nice day! ☺